# JSON value '<null>' of type while running it into ios android is working fine

Tags: react-native

I am getting weird response from RN iOS, it is working well into android but into iOS it getting error JSON value '' of type NSNull cannot be converted to NSString

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('view', {
  data: this.props.member.members ?  this.props.member.members :null,
  index: index,     
});
```

Please guide

Comment: data: this.props.member.members &&  (this.props.member.members)   can you try like that way

Comment: it does not work